# Parsing JSON in Phonegap simulator/iPhone vs. through browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am working on an iPhone app using Phonegap with just JS/HTML5 on the front-end and .NET on the back-end. For the login I am just making a call to the web service and get JSON back. The problem I am having is when debugging this in the desktop browser vs. debugging it on the actual phone/simulator.

The JSON that is retrieved looks like this when there is a valid login:

```
{"AuthToken":null,"Errors":[],"Success":true,"Message":null,"IsValid":true}
```

So I have this Ajax `success` function (jQuery):

```
success: function (data) {
    //this works on phone, but not in browser
    var success = data.Success;  //returns true             
    //this works in browser, but errors out on phone
    var dta = JSON.parse(data);
   success = dta.Success //returns true;
}
```

Any idea why this might happen or how I can correct it?  It's just easier for me to debug in the browser using Firebug instead of always using the simulator. I have been using some other debug methods (Weinre for one) but none are as good as using Firebug.

Comment: Is the problem something to the extent of it acting like its not getting the JSON object from the returned data?

Comment: Yes. The data is being returned (I can trace it out), just each medium is handling it differently.

Comment: var dta = JSON.parse(data) basically errs out on the iphone

Comment: Can you wrap the JSON.parse in a try/catch and alert/console.log the error message?

Comment: On the iphone it says "unable to parse JSON string"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem yesterday, went smoothly on the iPhone but not on the web, annoying.

After some searching I found that, if you set the `dataType: 'jsonp'`, and set a callback function `jsonp: 'jsoncallback'`

My handler looks something like this:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event){
        var myData = $(this).serialize();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'www.mysite.com/submit.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: myData,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                alert('success: ' + data)
                },
            error:  function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert('error')
                }
            });
        return false;
        })
```

On the server side I end off with:

```
echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($myData) . ');'
```

Something about the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) since your local directory is not in the same domain as your server.  Apparently jsonp (p for padded) can work cross domain, I'll post the article explaining this as soon as I find it.

**UPDATE:** [Here's where I got the tipoff](http://samcroft.co.uk/2011/updated-loading-data-in-phonegap-using-jquery-1-5/) maybe you've googled it already

Wish I could give you the .NET code but I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Simple little thing..

needed to add dataType: "json" for a parameter on the call for it to work on the web side.